# why CCDF of x is equal to expectd value of probability of x given y

Tags: probability, expectation

I found in an article a fact that is commonly used in scientific papers which mentions that:

$\mathbb{P}(f(r)>T) = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{P}(f(r)>T\,|\,r)]$

($\mathbb{E}$ is with respect to $r$)

That means the CCDF of $f(r)$ is equal to the expectation ,with respect to $r$, of the probability of $f(r)$ greater than $T$ given $r$.

I tried to prove this fact but without any success. Can someone help me to prove that? Is it true?

Thanks.

Comment: More generally, $P(A)=E(P(A\mid X))$ for every event $A$ and random variable $X$. Any idea in this wider setting?

Answer (score 1):

By relying on the tower property of conditional expectation, and the fact that the expectation $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_{\{A\}}]$ of the indicator function is just the probability $\mathbb{P}(A)$ of the event on which the indicator function is defined, you have the following chain of equalities:
$$
\mathbb{P}[f(r)>T]= \mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{1}_{\{f(r)>T\}}\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_{\{f(r)>T\}}|\,r]\right]=
\mathbb{E} \left[ \mathbb{P}(f(r)>T\,|\,r) \right].$$

Comment: Thank you very much Pasriv, I get it now. But it remains just a small point: given that there is other random variables in the equation of f(r) (i.e: f(r,x,y)), why the expectation is with respect to r ?